# Cannot click button to dismiss the message

Tags: html, css, django

I have this code on my template which shows an alert message on the screen when user is logged in and it contains a dismiss button. I've managed to center it in the screen. However, I cannot click on the button -  probably because of the header, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. How do I make the button clickable?

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="float:none;margin:auto;padding:15px">
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <strong>Hello {{ user.username }}! You have successfully logged in!</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: just a side comment: who uses django anyway? it's a messed up idea to put Python as an interpreter for HTML

Comment: @FlashThunder. Thank you for advise. Just learning Django. Could you please point out what is the proper way.

Comment: I mean that using some PHP framework would be more effective and easier to find help. To not to mention about a job. PHP was meant to do such a things from beginning, Python was introduced to that role forcefully, synthetically. Of course you can use whatever you want, but... I would rethink the choice. PHP is much easier to learn as well.